# Selenium chromedriver how disable translation bar in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, translation

When opening some web pages in [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) using [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) I found that chrome shows the translation bar in headless mode, but it doesn't show it when headless is disabled.

Example (headless enabled)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://blog.bellostes.com/?attachment_id=5392')
driver.save_screenshot('headless_true.png')

driver.quit()
```

Result:

[image]

Example (headless disabled)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = False
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://blog.bellostes.com/?attachment_id=5392')
driver.save_screenshot('headless_false.png')

driver.quit()
```

Result:

[image]

What I have already tried:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-features=TranslateUI')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-translate')  # Not supported any more on Chrome
```

No difference. Is any I can do to get rid of the translation bar in headless mode?